# how to set variable through views in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

how to set any variable in views so that its value i will get in template

home.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>To-Do lists</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Your To-Do list</h1>
    <form method="POST">
    <input id="id_new_item" name="item_text" placeholder="Enter a To-Do item"/>
    {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
    <table id="id_list_table">
        <tr><td>1 : {{new_item_text}}</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from lists.models import Item

def home_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_item_text = request.POST['item_text'] #
        print new_item_text;
        Item.objects.create(text=new_item_text) #
    else:
        new_item_text = '' #
    item = Item()
    item.text = request.POST.get('item_text', 'A new list item')
    item.save()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {
        'new_item_text': new_item_text
    })
```

MODELS.PY

```
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(default='')
```

This is the test that is failing
test.py

```
def test_home_page_returns_correct_html(self):
    request = HttpRequest() #
    response = home_page(request) #
    self.assertIn('A new list item', response.content.decode())
    expected_html = render_to_string('home.html',
        {'new_item_text': 'A new list item'}
    )
    self.assertEqual(response.content.decode(), expected_html)
```

the error is

```
AssertionError: 'A new list item' not found in u'<html>\n\t<head>\n\t\t<title>To-Do lists</title>\n\t</head>\n\t<body>\n\t\t<h1>Your To-Do list</h1>\n\t\t<form method="POST">\n\t\t<input id="id_new_item" name="item_text" placeholder="Enter a To-Do item"/>\n\t\t\n\t\t</form>\n\t\t<table id="id_list_table">\n\t\t\t<tr><td>1 : </td></tr>\n\t\t</table>\n\t</body>\n</html>\n'
```

please tell me the solutions or any material(any link) for question that i asked

Comment: OK. So what is (or is not) happening when you try this code? (And why are you creating the item twice?)

Comment: @DanielRoseman i am not getting what are you saying in  bracket . can you elaborate ?

Comment: You call `Item.objects.create(...)` in the POST block, which creates an Item, and then you instantiate *another* new Item and save it. Why?

Comment: However that has nothing to do with your failing test. Your test does not pass "A new list item" to request.POST, so I don't see how you expect it to work.

Comment: @DanielRoseman actully i am new to django and i wanted to set the variable and i want variable  "new_item_text" in template so suggest me any sample of code that is working  and rest of the code is dummy

Answer (score 0):

Templates get rendered with some context data, this is where you can pass through variables. In the case of Class Based Views as Imran suggested you can return your context from the

`get_context_data method`.

In function views you can pass context through to the render shortcut

`return render(request, 'my-template.html', {"variable1": True, "variable3": foo})`

Comment: i am writting {{variable1}} in template but nothing is getting there

Comment: Can you update the question with a snippet of your view code and template.

Answer (score -1):

you should use class based view

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'home.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['user']= self.request.user.username
    return context
```

in view you can simply access user as

```
{{user}}
```

Comment: This is not really an answer. The question was poorly posed to begin with, but there's no reason to recommend a class-based view over a functional one here.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Should i give the scenario which i am currently facing ?

Comment: @sagar of course. All questions should include sufficient context, plus the relevant code and a full description of what is not working.